# Collect values of pandas dataframe column A if column B is NaN (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe.

I want to collect/print the values of column A where column B is NaN.

**Question**
How do I do this?

**Edit**
Further:
Say I have a set of columns (b,c,d).
I want to select the values of column a if either b,c, or d is NaN.

(The trick for identifying NaNs is a bit different than simply "==" etc.)

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Not quite, but close.

Comment: sorry I forget that `class NanChecker: __eq__ = staticmethod(math.isnan)` is not common knowledge.  then you **can** simply do `float('nan') == NanChecker()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
     a  b  c
0  NaN  9  7
1  1.0  7  6
2  5.0  9  1
3  7.0  4  0
4  NaN  2  3
5  2.0  4  6
6  6.0  3  6
7  0.0  2  7
8  9.0  1  4
9  2.0  9  3

In [11]: df.loc[df['a'].isnull(), 'b']
Out[11]:
0    9
4    2
Name: b, dtype: int32
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [166]: df
Out[166]:
     a    b  c
0  NaN  5.0  3
1  7.0  NaN  8
2  4.0  9.0  7
3  8.0  NaN  9
4  3.0  0.0  5
5  NaN  3.0  5
6  9.0  0.0  3
7  0.0  2.0  6
8  7.0  8.0  7
9  1.0  7.0  6


In [163]: df[['a','b']].isnull().any(axis=1)
Out[163]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

In [164]: df.loc[df[['a','b']].isnull().any(axis=1)]
Out[164]:
     a    b  c
0  NaN  5.0  3
1  7.0  NaN  8
3  8.0  NaN  9
5  NaN  3.0  5

In [165]: df.loc[df[['a','b']].isnull().any(axis=1), 'c']
Out[165]:
0    3
1    8
3    9
5    5
Name: c, dtype: int32
```

Comment: I need to handle this with multiple columns, could you take a look at my edit @MaxU

Comment: You could also do `df.loc[df.a.isnull(), 'b']` and `df.loc[df.isnull().any(1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use np.isnan()

```
   df=       

   a     b 
 1 Nan   2 
 2 2     3 
 3 1     NaN

 for i in range(1,4):
      if np.isnan(df.loc[i,'a']):
            print(df.loc[i,'b'])
 out: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the .fillna() method to replace your NaNs.
You can also index to a specific column you would like to address rather than the whole data frame.

Here is a link to the docs: [DataFrame.fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
          0         1
0       NaN       NaN
1 -0.494375  0.570994
2       NaN       NaN
3  1.876360 -0.229738
4       NaN       NaN

In [8]: df.fillna(0)
Out[8]: 
          0         1
0  0.000000  0.000000
1 -0.494375  0.570994
2  0.000000  0.000000
3  1.876360 -0.229738
4  0.000000  0.000000
```